# Using readline's rl_insert_text on OS X 10.5

Tags: c, macos, readline

So, I'm trying to stuff some default text into a user input using readline, and having trouble getting it to work on OSX 10.5:

```
// rl_insert_text_ex.c
// gcc -o rl_insert_text_ex rl_insert_text_ex.c -lreadline
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int my_startup_hook(void) {
  return rl_insert_text("ponycorns");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *line;
  rl_startup_hook = (Function*) my_startup_hook;
  line = readline("What's your favorite mythical animal? ");
  if (NULL == line || '\0' == *line) {
    printf("Nothing given... :(\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("That's funny, I love %s too!\n", line);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't even compile on 10.4 (no definition for `_rl_insert_text` on 10.4, which is a bit of a bummer), but does compile on 10.5.  However, the `rl_insert_text()`'d text is never shown to screen, nor returned as user input.  The callback is being used and `rl_insert_text()` returns the proper value, (thank you, `printf`), so I'm not sure what's going on here.

I checked `/usr/include/readline/readline.h`, and `rl_insert_text()` is under:

```
/* supported functions */
```

which is confusingly under:

```
/*
 * The following is not implemented
 */
```

So am I SOL, or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged as ruby?  The code looks like C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you may be out of luck, at least with the readline library included in OS X. Due to license compatibility issues, Apple uses [libedit](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/), which (apparently) provides incomplete readline emulation. (This library is documented with the name "editline" in the `readline.h` included with OS X.)

[GNU Readline Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) (the "one true" readline library) is under GPL, which (being a copyleft license) does not play well with code that is not entirely open-source. If it comes down to (A) open-sourcing all of Xcode, OS X, etc. or (B) using a knock-off of what you're really like to use, Apple (like most companies) is always going to choose B. It's a bummer, but that's life.

Personally, I think this is one reason that GPL'd code is somewhat of a blight on the land, since in the act of "sticking it to the man", it often also withholds the code from the masses who purchase software. The {BSD,MIT,Apache}-style licenses are much more conducive to use in closed-source systems, and still allow commercial entities to contribute back patches, etc. My guess is that `libedit` hasn't received enough attention to be fixed properly. Community patches would certainly be welcome, although it's so much nicer if we can use code without having to hack on it ourselves... ;-)

BTW, the same thing applies to other GPL projects — <strike>as long as {git,mercurial,bazaar} remains under GPL, don't hold your breath for Apple to ship integration for them in Xcode. :-(</strike>

**UPDATE:** The new Xcode 4 offers git support. Huzzah! My understanding is that this is due to the new plugin architecture which isolates GPL'd code from the main Xcode codebase. However, I emphasize that copyleft licenses are still the wrong solution for code that should benefit everyone. Obviously some people don't agree (you're a pal, anonymous downvoter) but the fact is that [GPL can restrict freedoms too](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10784_3-9738466-7.html) — usually its different ones than closed-source/proprietary software generally does, but GPL is also quite effective at preventing illegal use of source code... The difference is a feeling of moral superiority.

Comment: Thanks!  This reaffirms my decision to just use editline() when on OS X.