# Prompt with editable default in c++?

Tags: c++, user-interface

Is is possible (without external library such as boost) to prompt for input from the user, like using cin, but with a default choice that is editable by the user (without a GUI)?

For example, the program will say:

```
Give your input: default
```

and the user can press enter to use "default" or press 1 then enter to get "default1", etc.

EDIT for clarification:

What I current have in my program is providing the default in the prompt (as in one of the answer below). But I'm writing for very special cases where having a editable default is extremely time saving (and 90% of the time, all the user needs is adding a suffix to the default). I can prompt for the suffix only, but then I lost flexibility to edit the default in the other 10% of the cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use [GNU readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

Comment: Specifically, you want `rl_insert_text()`.  Readline has some issues on OSX (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967029/using-readlines-rlinserttext-on-osx-10-5), but you can use the similar `editline` library instead (http://devworld.apple.com/dOcUmEnTaTiOn/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/editline.3.html), for which you'd want to use `el_insertstr()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done slightly differently than you've described. It's fairly common (at least as I've seen) to present the default option as *part of the prompt* rather than after it. For example:

```
Please enter a year (default: 2009):
```

or

```
Do you really want to exit (N):
```

This has the added advantage that if the user *does* want to enter his/her own value rather than the default, he/she doesn't need to delete an existing value in order to do so, which is poor usability and rather frustrating, especially if dealing with a long series of questions/prompts.

It also requires no special libraries and significantly less extra code.

Comment: Sometimes, though, an editable default is useful - like commit messages or in git or svn, or anytime you want to present an incomplete default to the user.

Comment: This is what I have now; but I'm writing for very special cases that having a editable default is extremely time saving (and 90% of the time all the user needs is adding a suffix to the default). I can prompt for the suffix only, but then I lost flexibility to edit the default in the 10% of cases.

Comment: @polyglot - write that into your question. The rationale is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily without an external library. All terminals handle this differently — unless you want to write a *lot* of code, you'll need a library. I suggest you look into [Ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: curses would be massive overkill for this use case