# Is it possible to prompt for user input and provide a default?

Tags: c++, command-line-tool

It is not uncommon to see a command-line program that prompts the user to enter a string to be processed in some way by the program. But is it possible to create a program that does this, and has a default value already there at the prompt - so that if the user wants to use the default value, they need only press Enter? (But if the user wants to use a different value, they will have to set about editing the pre-populated string - which might mean holding down backspace to delete it and then typing something else.)

Provisos:

- Needs to work on Windows. Well, for my purposes it needs to work on Windows. You can suggest a solution that only works on other OSes if you like, but I won't accept your answer.
- Needs to use only what is provided by the standard library.
- It's not sufficient to just say, "leave input empty to use the default value" - that's merely a workaround.

I've seen versions of this question that are specific to other languages, but not one for C++.

Comment: Note: if the solution has to use only what is provided by the Standard Library, then it *should* be guaranteed work on any OS, not just Windows. So requirement 1 is somehow implied by requirement 2.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible using the Standard Library alone, but I can't prove it either.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1103933/33732, but with the stipulation that solutions be limited to the standard library.

Comment: @RobKennedy then it's not a duplicate

Comment: A common alternative which is way easier to implement is to have a default which will be used if the input was empty (and print the default value so the user can see it), like: `Select language [en]:` - it is implemented just with a print statement (and flush, since the line is unterminated), a getline, and then the logic "if empty then use default".

Comment: There's a solution demonstrated in Python at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5888246/33732. The equivalent C++ code would use functions from kernel32, which your program will certainly be using, even if you don't explicitly include *windows.h*. Does that break your standard-library requirement, even though you're only interested in Windows solutions anyway?

Comment: Rob, I guess it would meet the actual need that motivated me to ask the question, though it wouldn't meet the standard of the question as I asked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One **can** do it using just the standard library.
But one **cannot** do it with just the guarantees provided by the standard library.

What you need to have, for any solution, is a way to control the terminal (which implies a guarantee about being connected to a terminal, and knowledge of the idiosyncrasies in controlling said terminal.

Unfortunately, the windows console window is not a proper terminal, which can be controlled that way.